# php code error Warning: Declaration of Digital_Signature::CreateSign()

Tags: php, rsa, pear

```
 function CreateSign()
{
$rsa_obj = new Crypt_RSA(array('private_key' => $this->_privateKey));
$this->check_error($rsa_obj);
return $rsa_obj->createSign($this->_document);
}
```

this code display this error

```
Warning: Declaration of Digital_Signature::CreateSign() should be compatible with Crypt_RSA::createSign($document, $private_key = NULL, $hash_func = NULL) in /var/www/html/shares/digital_signature.php on line 49
```

can any one help

Comment: https://pear.php.net/package/Crypt_RSA has been abandoned for years. phpseclib is the recommended alternative.

Comment: I have old web program , Transfer to new server , but icant run this program

Answer (score 0):

both functions in the parent class and child class should have the same arguments , also same default values for their arguments